# Create a boxplot per year out of a ts object in R

Tags: r, time-series, boxplot

I have a `ts` object: 240 monthly observations stating from January 2000:

```
data <- runif(240)

data_ts <- ts(data,
              start = c(2000, 1),
              frequency = 12)
```

And I want to create a boxplot per year out of my `data_ts`.

I know how to create a boxplot per month:

```
boxplot(data_ts ~ cycle(data_ts))
```

But I don't know how to create a boxplot per year, that is, a boxplot of the observations of each year (a boxplot of year 2000, a boxplot of 2001, and so on).

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be a good way to use dummy data `... ts(data = runif(240), ...`

Comment: When you say "boxplot per year", are you looking for multiple boxplots plots?

Comment: @M.Viking I've edited the question to answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year is given as shown:

```
year <- as.integer(time(data_ts))
boxplot(data_ts ~ year)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Simple and effective! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the `window()` function to subset the years, and a `for()` loop to iterate each year and create a `boxplot()`. The `title()` function adds the title to the plot, and `png()` and `dev.off()` work together to save the image to disk:

```
getwd() # print location files will be saved too.
for (i in 2010:2012) { # small loop for testing)
  png(file=paste("boxplot_",i,".png",sep=""))  # create a png
  boxplot(window(x=data_ts, start=c(i, 1), end=c(i, 12))) # boxplot, of yearly data.
  title(i) # add the year as a title to the plot
  dev.off() # save the png
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this also helps:

```
data <- runif(240)
data_ts <- ts(data,
              start = c(2000, 1),
              frequency = 12)

frame<-data.frame(values=as.matrix(data_ts), date=lubridate::year(zoo::as.Date(data_ts)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(frame,aes(y=values,x=date,group=date))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

It is not the most elegant solution though as it uses both the `zoo` and `lubridate` packages to convert the date into a year that ggplot understands.